# Foreign key constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths but only in one project

Tags: entity-framework-core

I've gone through the other questions on SO and none of them have helped in my instance, so please don't mark it as duplicate.   I downloaded and ran the method from the documentation to get a many-to-many linked table.   The sample project has

```
public class Book {
    [Key]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}
public class Category {
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}
public class BookCategory {
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

with

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
        .HasKey(bc => new { bc.BookId, bc.CategoryId });
    modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
        .HasOne(bc => bc.Book)
        .WithMany(b => b.BookCategories)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.BookId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
        .HasOne(bc => bc.Category)
        .WithMany(c => c.BookCategories)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.CategoryId);
```

in `OnModelCreating`.   This works fine and creates the correct migration file which works fine and looks like this

```
table.ForeignKey(
     table.ForeignKey(
    name: "FK_BookCategory_Book_BookID",
    column: x => x.BookID,
    principalTable: "Book",
    principalColumn: "BookID",
    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
table.ForeignKey(
    name: "FK_BookCategory_Category_CategoryID",
    column: x => x.CategoryID,
    principalTable: "Category",
    principalColumn: "CategoryID",
    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
```

Copying the code into my project and adding a migration creates the same migration file.   But, when I try to update the database I get the error

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_BookCategory_Category_CategoryID' on table 'BookCategory' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

Swapping the two `table.ForeignKey(` statements around means that the error refers to `FK_BookCategory_Book_BookID` and only having one of them the database is updated successfully.

Any ideas why the migration works in one project but not another?

Comment: Have you tried generating an sql script and running it against the database?

Comment: The generated SQL script creates the keys which cause the same problem.   And it means I can't use EF to do my migrations.

Comment: I have multiple many-to-many in my current project declared exactly like this and they all work fine. Try being explicit with the principal key and OnDelete behavior.

Comment: Do you mean add a `[Key]` to BookCategory ?   If so, I tried that and it didn't affect anything.   Sometimes when I generate the migration `FK_BookCategory_Category_CategoryID` has `ReferentialAction.Cascade` and sometimes `ReferentialAction.Restrict`.

Comment: If it generates it as `ReferentialAction.Restrict` and I change it to `cascase` sometimes it runs and sometimes doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {` I removed

```
.HasForeignKey(bc => bc.BookId);
```

and replaced it with

```
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

so it looked like this.

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
        .HasOne(bc => bc.Book)
        .WithMany(b => b.BookCategories)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
        .HasOne(bc => bc.Category)
        .WithMany(c => c.BookCategories)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

This removes the cascade part so everything works.   I've tested deleting records from each of the tables in SQL Management Studio and in code and none of the code cascades any deletes which means I'm happy.